# What are these weird Postgresql connection attempts on my Heroku app?

Tags: go, heroku, heroku-postgres

We updated our database from Hobby to a paid one (50$/mo).

We're constantly seeing these weird connection attempts (it's being logged hundreds of times daily), one after another (like 100 attempts in 5 seconds, and then a delay)

> 153XXX7XXXX   2022-12-07 11:XX:XX 2022-12-07
> 11:XX:XX  130057XXXX  appname 3.227.75.243    Local0  Error   app/postgres.209796 [GREEN]
> [9-1]  sql_error_code = 28000 time_ms = "2022-12-07 HIDDEN UTC"
> pid="25283" proc_start_time="2022-12-07 HIDDEN UTC"
> session_id="639HIDDEN" vtid="6/35726" tid="0" log_line="2"
> database="postgres" connection_source="159.HIDDEN(35786)"
> user="postgres" application_name="[unknown]" FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf
> entry for host "159.HIDDEN", user "postgres", database "postgres",
> no encryption

We have `connection_logging` and `lock_waits` enabled in the dashboard, but I don't think that's it.

[image]

Our app is a webserver written in `Go`. We're also directly connected through Jetbrain's `DataGrip` from our PC.

Is that connection attempt something default to Heroku?

Comment: Not sure if Heroku exposes the `pg_hba.conf` since they manage the DB. The error is related to the connecting client not being present in that config. Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host